# How to search an array of objects with a keyword that can match values to more than one property using filter

Tags: javascript, loops, search, filter

```
const heroes = [
  {name: "Batman", realName: "Bruce Wayne", universe: "DC"},
  {name: "Superman", realName: "Clark Kent", universe: "DC"},
  {name: "Iron Man", realName: "Tony Stark", universe: "Marvel"},
  {name: "Star Lord", realName: "Peter Quill", universe: "Marvel"},
  {name: "Venom", realName: "Eddie Brock", universe: "Marvel"}
]

function search(lookup){
  const result = heroes.filter(each => {
    return each.name.toLowerCase().includes(lookup.toLowerCase())  || 
           each.universe.toLowerCase().includes(lookup.toLowerCase())
  })
  return result
}
console.log(search("DC"))
```

If I search by name "Batman" I will return the first object.  If I search "DC" I will return the first two objects.  I'm getting the results I want but what other ways can I iterate over heroes instead of using the || operator? If I wanted to also search by realName I would have to add another return value and I would appreciate input on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you, it works with just parts of those names too:

```
const typedWord = "DC"; 
const list = [{name: "Batman", company: "DC"}, {name: "Spiderman", company: "Marvel"}]

const filteredList = list.filter(function (object) {
    const entries = Object.entries(object).map((entry) => { return entry[0] })
    var matches = entries.filter((entry) => { return object[entry].includes(typedWord) })
    return matches.length !== 0
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're searching for a way to look at all of the *values* within a given object. This would be a great place to use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), which returns an array of each value in the object, so your first object would look like:

```
["Batman", "Bruce Wayne", "DC"]
```

Great! Now if you have a search term, let's call it `lookup` for ease of examples, you can *loop* through (or use the `.includes()` JS functionality like you did) this array you create with `Object.values()` like so:

```
const result = heroes.filter(each => {
    let objectValues = Object.values(each);

    return objectValues.includes(lookup);
})
```

I took out some portions of your code like the greater function of this snippet and how you are making doing the comparisons with lowercased strings, but I leave that as a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function search(lookup){
    return heros.filter(hero =>{
           return Object.values(hero).filter(value => value.includes(lookup))
        })
   }
```